# Best way to translate month names

Tags: php, codeigniter, time

I am using Codeigniter! What will be the best way to translate month names. I have a date in mysql timestamp like this:
        `2012-09-22 11:21:53`
I can  convert it to `'September 22, 2012'` with php `date()` function. I want to rename `'September'` to `'Sentýabr'`. Can set_locale() function can do this. By the way it is `Turkmen Language`.
 thank you.

---

OK , i created some php file to check it indivudally like this:

cool.php

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL,'ru_RU');
echo strftime('%B',time());
?>
```

Returns September. What might be the problem.

---

I have

```
  /* Set locale to Turkmen */
  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tk');
```

And

```
  echo strftime( '%B',time());
```

Result: returns September

I need it return September in my language

Comment: A way to translate weekdays and months from or into any language (provided the language is installed on the php server), is to be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465351/translating-php-weekdays-and-months/43577566#43577566

Comment: strftime deprected in php8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `str_ireplace()` with arrays for names in english, and equivalent for names in turkmen, in same order.

Something like this:

```
$nmeng = array('january', 'february', ..);
$nmtur = array('ocak', 'subat', ...);
$dt = 'September 22, 2012';
$dt = str_ireplace($nmeng, $nmtur, $dt);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I did it with your help :)

Comment: This is not a good way to do it...

This is better!
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR');
strftime('%e de %B de %Y', strtotime('2012-09-22 11:21:53'));

Answer (score 12):

Use `setlocale()` and [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) ...

On linux run `$ locale -a` to find out if the needed locale is installed and to grab its name value string.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU');
echo strftime('%B %e, %Y', strtotime('2012-09-22 11:21:53'));
```

***Edit:***

If you use a windows server, then change `%e` to `%d` (`%e` does not work in windows).

```
echo strftime('%B %d, %Y', strtotime('2012-09-22 11:21:53'));
```

For windows, *[check here to see supported format.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx)*

Comment: Where do I find Country extension?

Comment: What would be the code for this?..

Comment: Can write example code how to format this September to 'September-in_russian'

Comment: @NewKid Added the code, check it.

Comment: @xdazz it returned error ( Error: Invalid CRT parameters detected )

Answer (score 2):

best way to translate month names to put them in language file and call it like read here how to use language files in codeigniter [Language library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html) you can use in you project over and over if you have dual language site.

```
$this->lang->line('September');

your english language file 
$lang['january'] = 'january';
$lang['february'] = 'february';
...
$lang['September'] = 'September';

your turkish language file 

$lang['january'] = 'ocak';
$lang['february'] = 'subat';
...
$lang['September'] = 'Eylül';
```

Comment: i have used the same thing for dual language site has arabic and english and it works really great. you have to do little effort to put translation in both files

Comment: how do i replace date('%F') %F to $this->lang->line('September')

Comment: $this->lang->line(date('%F')) will work you have to pass month name as parameter and it will return translation remember $lang key name should be same as string you are passing

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the index.php file near the top:

```
/* Set locale to Turkmen */
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tk');
```

Documentation for this is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Also, @xdazz is correct that you should combine it with [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) instead of the date() function.

You may need to confirm that "tk" is used for Turkmen.

Comment: I have this :echo strftime( "F d Y",strtotime($post->entry_date)); It returns just " F d Y"

Comment: It still returns September,not in my language

Comment: Have you confirmed that "tk" is the string for Turkmen? I may have it incorrect (cursory Google search).

Comment: Also, did you add setlocale() to your site's index.php file?

Comment: yes i added it to index.php file

Comment: Well, doing with strings (the answer you selected) is not functional if you always have to make sure the output is set to the proper locale. If you can make sure your PHP instance supports `setlocale()` then you won't ever have to worry about the translation being done for your output.